# Symmetric operator on a certain linear space.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $$Ly=-y''+q(x)y$$ an operator on the linear space $$V=\{\varphi\in\mathcal{C}^2[0,1]:\varphi(0)=\varphi(1)=0\}$$ we have to prove that this operator is symmetric i.e. if $\varphi,\psi\in V$ then 
$$\int_0^1\psi L\varphi=\int_0^1\varphi L\psi$$ 
**My try:** Replacing the operator in both integrals by the formula given and integrating by parts once we get to that $$\int_0^1 q\varphi =\int_0^1q\psi$$ then i reduce the problem to that. But i don't know how to justify this equality.

If someone can help me i would be grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is

$$\int_0^1 \psi(x)L\phi(x)\,dx = \int_0^1 \psi(x)(\phi''(x)+q(x)\phi(x))\,dx.$$

We don't need to adjust the second term, merely the first. To get it in the form you want, integrate the first term by parts twice.

Comment: Thanks. My mistake. I solved the problem after your observation.

Comment: It happens to the best of us! Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_0^1\psi L\varphi=-\int_0^1\psi \varphi'' +\int_0^1q\psi\varphi=\underbrace{-\psi\varphi'\Bigg|_0^1}_{=0}+\underbrace{\int_0^1\psi'\varphi'+ \int_0^1q\psi\varphi}_{\text{expression symmetric on}\;\psi\;\text{and}\;\varphi}$$

so we can interchange the role of $\psi$ and $\varphi$ to get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks i made a mistake when i compute the integral. +1